# In what dialect is "on" used of a programming language?

Tags: prepositions, dialects

I have noticed that it is common on StackOverflow for questions to use "on ⟨programming language⟩" where American English would require "in". For example, "[Is there a getInt function on Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38313564/is-there-a-getint-function-on-haskell)". Is there a particular English dialect where this usage is common, or is this more likely a mistake by a non-native speaker?

Comment: I doubt it's really a usage you could say is "dialectal", or "regionalised" in any meaningful way. Obviously *some* native speakers will conflate *Operating Systems* (which you often *develop **on*** or ***under***) and *languages* (and/or associated programmer workbenches). But I expect there will be far more *non-native* speakers prone to mistakenly use the non-idiomatic preposition. Certainly many of the instances I can easily find in Google Books have author names suggesting they might not be native speakers, but I haven't examined surrounding text to investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a short answer is just that I, as a Brit, have never heard anyone say *on [language]* and I, as a programmer, have always said *in [language]*. 
Indeed a cursory search of Google books would suggest that the phrasing *[program on](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=onqEV4KSE8HCgAbm-LbICQ&q=program%20on&oq=&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.1.0.41.17752.19051.0.22871.10.8.0.1.1.0.196.934.1j6.7.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..7.3.371.1..0.5KmWCew44ZA)* (presumably followed by the name of a language in this case) is mainly used  in AmE to say something like

> This is a programme on compound semiconductors.

More in the sense of a research trial or as the OED puts it:

> A set of related measures or activities with a particular long-term aim:
>   *the British nuclear power programme*

While on the other hand *[program in](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=u3qEV6DbL6TdgAbtgK_AAw&q=program+in&oq=program+in&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...3297.5327.0.5750.4.4.0.0.0.0.124.430.2j2.4.0....0...1c..64.mobile-gws-serp..0.2.235...0j41.Dy0qyiARCSE)* comes up with lots of references to computer programming, for example:

> How Not to Program In C++

(The top search result)

Furthermore, a Google search [specifically of Stack Overflow](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=program%20on%20site:stackoverflow.com&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-gb&client=safari) shows that the phrasing *program on* is more often used in reference to operating systems or devices and not individual programs or languages.

Finally, if we look at the phrase *[program in](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=program%20in%20site:stackoverflow.com&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-gb&client=safari)* from Stack Overflow it comes up with lots of references to

> I program in [given language]

I would therefore suggest that you always use **in** as the preposition here if you're talking about a language.

Answer (score 0):

The person who said "on Haskell" is someone called Mario from the Universidad de Granada. The chances are that he is not a native English speaker. He is probably Spanish. It's very easy to get prepositions wrong in foreign languages. Mario simply got it wrong. I've been a professional software developer for many years, and I've never heard anyone say "on [programming language]".

Comment: The reason I asked is that I've been mistaken about such things in the past. Indian English often surprises me, and there are surely others I'm even less familiar with.